# Obtain JSON response from URL with AJAX using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm relatively new to Javascript and I'm stuck trying to obtain a JSON data from an URL using AJAX.

The url returns an array on characters that I want to request/obtain and then handle the data to show it in html. That url is:
http://stark-tundra-9859.herokuapp.com/locations

The code that I'm using is the following, and the problem is that it appears as if I received nothing for response. Besides I dont know what the request info variable should be:

```
function ajax_request() {

requestInfo='';

var params = JSON.stringify(requestInfo);

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'http://stark-tundra-9859.herokuapp.com/locations',
  data: params,
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
  converters: {
    'text json': true
  },

  success: function(response) {
    $("#responseParagraph").html(response);

  },
  error: function(error) {
    $("#responseParagraph").html(error.responseText);

  }
});

}
```

@agam360, I also have done a version of this code using JQUERY and I do receive a message in the console which goes as follows:

GET http://stark-tundra-9859.herokuapp.com/locations 200 OK 198ms

Response header
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  154
Content-Type    application/json;charset=utf-8
Server  thin 1.5.1 codename Straight Razor
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff

Request header
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Connection  keep-alive
Host    stark-tundra-9859.herokuapp.com
Origin  null
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0

The code used to receive that answer is the following:

```
function json_request() {

$.getJSON(url,
    function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $('#responseParagraph').append("<p>"+data.responseMessage+"</p>");
    });

}
```

In this JQUERY very It seems as if I dont receive the DATA from the JSON request correctly. Maybe I am handling it erronously?

I would greatly appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: Since this appears to be a foreign domain and it seems to only return JSON (and not JSONP), you can't use Ajax to directly connect to it. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy.

Comment: Is your website also running on `stark-tundra-9859.herokuapp.com`?

Comment: Also, I don't you can use `contentType: "application/json"` (or `JSON.stringify`) with a GET request (P.S. `contentType` is for the request, not the response).

Comment: It is indeed a foreign domain (which I set up for testing), so @FelixKling which one would be my solution here to request this JSON data from this URL?

Comment: @JoseSabas, isn't the json_request() working? what happens now?

Comment: @agam360 I do get a responde with the function json_request() but it appears as if I am not receiving the data from the URL, or probably I'm handling it wrongly?

Comment: @JoseSabas, what does alert(data) show? nothing? (try console.log(data) instead). In addition, are you sure you haven't seen any messages in the console looking like: "...s not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. "?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question I will need to ask you two things:
1) On what domain are you running this script? (on the same server as "http://stark-tundra-9859.herokuapp.com/" ?)
Because that URL does not allow [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)

2) Open up your console (in chrome: Ctrl+shift+j) and tell us what error message 
you get, if you get any.

If your answer to the first question is **no** (meaning you are not running the script on the same host) then, if you have control over that page, enable CORS by sending the following header (*please read some info about this, related to security before implementing*):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

More language specific implementations can be found on [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/server.html)
(You can also read about '[JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)' implementations regarding cross domain requests - if your not willing to use CORS).

On the other hand, (your answer is **yes**), we will need to see your server-side related code, and any error messages thrown on the client side.

**Note:** From what I see (as to now - 5 minutes after posting my answer), the http://stark-tundra-9859.herokuapp.com/locations URL returns a "***500 - Internal server error***" - Your problem seems to be related to server side of things.

**Update,**
You need to acess your data as a JSON object after you got it,
like so:

```
data[0].lat // will hold the lat value of the first object in the JSON wrapper object
```

As to implementing JSONP with jQuery, I ran a quick search in SO, here is something you will probably want to take a look at: [jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Comment: Thanks @agam360, To answer your questions: 1)No, I'm not running this script on the same domain. 2) The console appears blank, no messages at all.

Comment: Do you have any control over that page? can you allow (or did you try to allow) CORS? did you try using JSONP?

Comment: I beleive it is possible for me to add CORS (never heard of it before though). And NO I havent try using JSONP, why yo say so, should it work with JSONP?

Comment: @JoseSabas, Client-side code (that isn't originating from the same host) can't just request every page it desires if not allowed by the page/host. To overcome this situation you can use CORS (allow external JavaScript to access your page) or JSONP which does a neat trick in order to achieve the same result. If you are running the script externally (e.g. from a different host) and you want it to access that page, use one of those techniques.

Comment: All right @agam360 perfect, thanks. I'll try to make my way with JSONP. Anny suggestions to achieve that neat trick ?, lol

Comment: @JoseSabas, did you really get things working? if not try using what I wrote in my updated answer section, and my comment in your question.

Comment: thanks bro, right now Im reading all the documentation to try to make this work. I'll post any problems later and I will let you know,